# Reality Check on Forest Placement

Tags: internal-consistency, environment

I'm trying my hand at this new map-making program and while I know the basics of rivers and mountains, I realized I don't know the fundamentals of where to put forests. I've tried to follow the rules I could find (forests by rivers, hugging the bases of mountains) but I wanted to check here if the forests are all right. Thank you all in advance!

P.S The only 'unnatural' landforms on the map are GH45 and E7. For details on wind, winds arrive from the West, Northwest and North. Latitude is supposed to be temperate zone, right before the arctic zone at A1-A11.[image: Sorry if unclear. Original image is HD but too large to upload]

Comment: Very difficult to know if the forests are in the right place with nothing to go on but this map. I can't really tell what is mountain. Is it supposed to be islands and the dark area is ocean? Pretty unclear.

Comment: Yes, please provide a less stylised map that makes this stuff more obvious.

Comment: Those round circular bays look like big craters.  What was the map program you used?

Answer (score 5):

A couple quick and perhaps obvious requirements:

1) below the treeline -- altitude at which annual low temps kill the trees.
2) somewhere with the water table reasonably close to the surface. 
3) somewhere not completely underwater, save for specific species (see types in Southern bayous of the USA).

After that, it's pretty much all Darwin:  can tree species compete successfully for water, minerals, and sunlight vs. bushes, grasses,  fungi, etc.

And finally, make your borders fractals so as to look "natural."